# how to get value from activity to class databasehelper?

Tags: android

This is my `class databasehelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper`

```
public List<Product>getListIndo(){
        Product product = null;
        List<Product>productList = new ArrayList<>();`enter code here`
        openDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = mDatabase.rawQuery("select * from product, null);
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()){
            product = new Product(cursor.getInt(0),cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3),cursor.getString(4),cursor.getString(5));
            productList.add(product);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }
        cursor.close();
        closeDatabase();
        return  productList;
    }
```

Comment: Pass it as a constructor (or method) param.

Answer (score 0):

Which value do you want to pass to the databasehelper? You are using `select` method in your sql query which means to retrieve data from the table `product`not insert. If you insert something into database you have to use `INSERT INTO table_name`